# How to merge two arrays based on their index php?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge 2 arrays and i have found lot of examples here on stackoverflow, but nothing has worked for me, in my case, so i explain my case:

**Arrays (can be one, two, or three, or more...):**

```
Array ( [0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png- 
        [1] => name-file_icon_002_00.png-
        [2] => name-file_icon_003_00.png- )
Array ( [0] => rel
        [1] => rel
        [2] => rel )
```

**Or can be two:**

```
Array ( [0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png- 
        [1] => name-file_icon_002_00.png- )
Array ( [0] => rel
        [1] => rel )
```

**Or one:**

```
Array ( [0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png- ) 
Array ( [0] => rel )
```

Need to insert the relative value "`[0] => rel`" with "`[0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png-`"

**Expected result (merged):**

```
Array ( [0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png-rel
        [1] => name-file_icon_002_00.png-rel
        [2] => name-file_icon_003_00.png-rel )
```

Reading around the web, seems that not exist a native function for make this.
Please, hope in your help :)

Comment: _seems that not exist a native function for make this_ Then you shoudl write some code to do it

Comment: Rereading, but it seems you can concatenate both arrays at their matching indices to get your result?

Comment: I have try with `foreach` loop in another loop, but have got bad results

Comment: You could use `foreach($item as $index => $value)` and then access the array by value and the other by `$index` if they are of equal length, then concatenate the two values. If I'm understanding your problem specification correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple foreach loop using the index and value parameters will do it in no time

Example

```
$a1 = ['name-file_icon_001_00.png-',
        'name-file_icon_002_00.png-',
        'name-file_icon_003_00.png-'
        ];
$a2 = ['rel1','rel2','rel3'];

foreach ($a1 as $i => $v){
    $new[] = $v . $a2[$i];
}
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => name-file_icon_001_00.png-rel1
    [1] => name-file_icon_002_00.png-rel2
    [2] => name-file_icon_003_00.png-rel3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map each array to a function that concatenates them:

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a.$b; }, $one, $two);
```

If you define one array with subarrays then you can unpack that array `...`:

```
$array = [$one, $two];
$result = array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a.$b; }, ...$array);
```

Or for fun, you can extract each column from the subarrays and `implode` them:

```
$array = [$one, $two];
for($i=0; $a=array_column($array, $i); $i++) {
    $result[] = implode($a);
}
```

Comment: I see they are separate arrays I am editing.

Comment: For my knowledge is enough difficult understand your code, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, that's how you learn not just take code and use it.